# How can I avoid WebSocketHandshakeException for shouldBeAbsent headers in java client?

Tags: websocket, java-9

With JDK9, I can see the following request & response pair:

request

```
Sec-WebSocket-Key:  30OwU9P2rjT/qWL3QC0kmw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:  13
```

response

```
101 HTTP_1_1
cf-ray: 3bd0f4b01edd7880-LAX
connection: upgrade
date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 10:13:00 GMT
sec-websocket-accept: BKivHQBCLbWp/Wt+a/adShOiReo=
sec-websocket-version: 13
server: cloudflare-nginx
set-cookie: __cfduid=d67ffb74a74787b4a8d115b303c9932b11510567979;   expires=Tue, 13-Nov-18 10:12:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.bitfinex.com; HttpOnly
upgrade: websocket
websocket-server: uWebSockets
```

My problems is that I got WebSocketHandshakeException with message
Response field 'Sec-WebSocket-Version' present: [13].

I do not understand why at the point, the client side require the header 'Sec-WebSocket-Version' should not present. If the server sends it, why the client can not just ignore it, but throw handshake exception? Anyone knows why this exception happened? Thanks.